# Get precise location every 1 minute in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on concept of guard application where in i need guard actual location every 60 seconds. same functionality was working in iOS 12, but in iOS 13 and 14 not working as it should be. i have made below changes for location manager.

```swift
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.distanceFilter = 2
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
locationManager.activityType = .other
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

am getting precise location when app is in foreground, but as soon as app goes background am not getting actual location. it would be great if any one can help me out as its causing the productivity of app and its basic usage.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure to read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background) first.

Apart from setting the `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to `true`, you also need to check the “Location updates” capability for your app in Xcode.

[image]

> When a location update occurs while your app is in the background, the system launches your app and passes an options dictionary to the application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods. The dictionary may contain the location key to indicate that location services caused the app to launch.

Answer (score 0):

Request the `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, if you are going to use the user’s location in the background.

```swift
let authorizationStatus =  CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways {
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
} else {
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}
```

And also update the Info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
```